# How to detect property changed in base class

Tags: .net, propertychanged

I created a custom control inherited from `Label`, I added a string property `SecondLanguageText`.

I want to detect when the `RightToLeft` property of base class (`Label`) changed to replace text property with new property `SecondLanguageText`, I want to do that by adding an event `OnRightToLeftChanged` fired when the `RightToLeft` property changed

Comment: What language? Do you have some example code?

Comment: @Rob he said `.net` code in the pre-edited body of the question, but did not qualify it further

Comment: What you want to achieve is not clear. Why don't you use the built-in righttoleftchanged ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleftchanged.aspx